# How to access public folder in laravel 4?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I was trying to add some styling in my localhost(wamp) lavarel project....

This is my style.css file located in public folder

```
p{font-weight:bold; size:20px; color:red;}
```

This is hello.blade.php file located in app/view folder

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('style.css') }}">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Test</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

& My routes.php file is having following code:

```
Route::get('/',function(){
  return View::make('hello');
});
```

.htaccess file located in root directory is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>
RewriteEngine On
# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

When I am trying to access that hello page by localhost, Test content is visible without any styling. Can anyone tell me what is going wrong with me??

Comment: does `localhost/public/` display the `hello` content?

Comment: nopes...i can access hello page only by localhost

Comment: view the hello html page source code, get the css url inside the `link` tag, copy the link to new browser tab to see if it is available.

Comment: Link of css is http://localhost/style.css which is not accessible directly and giving "NotFoundHttpException" error in laravel 4

Comment: Please show us your `.htaccess` file in the public folder

Comment: added in the question...please check...

Comment: The content looks fine however you wrote "located in root directory" is it in the root directory of the application or in the public directory?

Comment: it is outside public directory..public directory has only blank index.php page...

Comment: Have you changed the default Laravel directory structure for some reason?

Comment: No...my directory structure is as attached image http://myraipur.com/1.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your directory structure is different from the default one shown [here](https://github.com/laravel/laravel)

You have to put the `packages` folder and these files into the public directory:

- .htaccess
- favicon.ico
- index.php
- robots.txt

Then to make your site work again change the document root of your apache server to `path/to/application/public`

There's a reason for the `public` directory. When you put it on a server on the internet you gain additional security because the user can only access what is in the `public` directory. (because the domain is pointing to this folder) If you use your current setup everybody could see your whole application. For example one could enter `example.com/app/config/database.php` and would see your database password.

Comment: Thanks lukasgeiter ...it worked..though i had to add virtual host...but your suggestion was very useful...

Comment: A virtual host is even better than changing the document root!

Answer (score -1):

Put it like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('style.css') }}">
```

Without URL::

Comment: This doesn't make any difference. `asset()` is just a helper function that calls `URL::asset`